# Insert results of concat

Tags: mysql, insert, concat

I have a table with 4 columns:

```
ID     ORDER_ID     QTY     VALUE     
1       153          1        0
2       476          1        0
3       453          9        1
4       719          2        2
```

With this table, I have to concat " " to the values of QTY and VALUE and then store it back in the table, so it can look like this (Both, `qty` and `value` are TEXT):

```
ID     ORDER_ID     QTY     VALUE     
1       153         "1"      "0"
2       476         "1"      "0"
3       453         "9"      "1"
4       719         "2"      "2"
```

To concat the values, I use the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT('"',qty,'"') qty, 
CONCAT('"',`VALUE`,'"') VALUE
FROM `myTable`;
```

Now, when I try to use:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`order_id`, `qty`, `value`) 
SELECT `order_id`, CONCAT('"',qty,'"') , CONCAT('"',value,'"')  
FROM `1.1`;
```

This basically blanks my entire table.

However, if I use a single concat, I can get the desired output stored but the rest of the fields are blank.

```
 INSERT INTO `myTable` (`qty`) 
    SELECT CONCAT('"',qty,'"')
 FROM `1.1`;
```

Sorry if this is a newb question but I did try to search no to avail.

Thank You.

Comment: Shoudnt you have value in the second CONCAT?And check the column type in your new table for value.

Comment: Changed, was just copy/pasted wrong. Also column type checks out fine. =(  Thank You!

Comment: Edit your question with myTable defintion.